# Custom background color does not cover whole background

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color

I've written a simple custom style in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_light</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/background_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

However, when I apply it, the text color is correctly set for every element of the view, whereas the background color is not set for the whole screen, but only for the single views inside it (for example listviews, textviews, buttons).

This is the code I use to set the theme:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    this.setTheme(R.android.Light);
    super.onCreate(icicle);
```

How can I change the background color for the whole layout?

Comment: give some transparent border for your background and try.

Comment: @PadmaKumar can you explain better?

Comment: Could you post the code/XML showing how you're applying your theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_light</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_light</item>
```

> Note that the color needs to supplied as a separate resource here because the `android:windowBackground` attribute only supports a reference to another resource; unlike `android:colorBackground`, it can not be given a color literal.

(quoted from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Sorry, I could not find more information than what is already in the post. I would just set them both and see if there will show up any differences.

Answer (score -1):

You must apply a theme to an Activity or application to apply the background image across the whole application.

Here is a link [check out this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)